# Copy section of video into texture in WebGL

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, webgl

I'm trying to copy a very large video (5k+ resolution) into a WebGL texture to use in a shader. I ran into the issue that on certain browsers (Firefox in particular), that texture copy would always take multiple hundreds of milliseconds. My attempted solution was using two textures and copying halves of the video into those textures but I had issues syncing them, so I'm back at the original problem.

Since both of these calls block for hundreds of milliseconds

```
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, video);
```

```
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 2880, 2880, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
gl.texSubImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, video);
```

I was hoping there exists a way to copy a section of the video into two textures, hopefully cut in half horizontally. From testing I know slightly smaller textures (even 2880 by 2880) run in realtime.

Does such a call exist in WebGL? I can use WebGL2 if it exists there.